# Javascript: Change bgColor of a table cell

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color of one specific cell in my table:
Why does the following not work?

```
document.getElementById('myTable').rows[i].cells[j].bgColor="#mybgColor";
```

where `i` and `j` are some integers certainly within the range of the rows and cells.
I don't need any fancy JQuery or so, just this simple command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS styles will override the `bgColor` attribute, which is deprecated.  Use **`.style.backgroundColor`** instead of `.bgColor`:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#003366";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
object.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just happen to really like bgColor, or you need to change an attribute; use this:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').rows[i].cells[j].setAttribute('bgColor', 'red');
```

[**setAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
...cells[0].style.bgColor = '#002200';
```

Comment: there is no `style.bgColor` css attribute.

Comment: @gilly3: you are right I upvote him as I forgot that there is no attribute **bgColor** in css, but thanks for your correction.